# Execute a saved graphDB SPARQL Query

Tags: curl, sparql, graphdb

How do you execute a saved (shared) graphDB-SPARQL-Query with curl?

```
$ curl http://192.168.188.23:7200/repositories/01?savedQueryName=myquery
```

does not work, graphdb asks for the query (Missing parameter: query)

thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

The REST API for the saved queries is GET /rest/sparql/saved-queries. Your request should look like this.

```
curl http://localhost:7200/rest/sparql/saved-queries?name=myquery
```

You can check all endpoints at /webapi in the Workbench.

Comment: It is apparently not possible to execute the saved query directly

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Queries are saved per Workbench instance, not per GraphDB repository.

So you also need to set the default repo, so that GDB query knows against which repo to run the query. See

- manually: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/creating-a-repository.html#make-it-a-default-repository
- programmatically: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/devhub/workbench-rest-api/curl-commands.html

```
curl -X POST <base_url>/rest/locations/default-repository -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '
{
    "repository": "<repo_id>"
}'
```

mr_sol, what exactly doesn't work for you?